# Cannot assign variable value inside Do Loop

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming, assignment

This is more of a conceptual problem.

Suppose I have three lists.

```
x1 = {1, 2, 9, 10};
x2 = {5, 6, 7};
x3 = {9, 10, 13};
```

Now, I wish to keep only the first two elements of each list. More precisely, I want

```
x1= {1, 2};
x2 = {5, 6};
x3 = {9, 10};
```

One easy way to do is,

```
x1=x1[[{1,2}; x2=x2[[{1,2}]]; x3=x3[[{1,2}]];
```

So far, it is okay. But it won't work if I try to do the same using the `Do[]` loop. For example,

```
Do[i=i[[{1,2}]],{i,{x1,x2,x3}];
```

do not assign new values to `x1,x2,x3.`

I also tried,

```
(#=#[[{1,2}]])&/@{x1,x2,x3}
```

But it didn't work.

I don't understand the reason behind this. What will be the correct way to assign variables/lists in a `Do[]` loop?

Comment: You can use 
`#[[{1, 2}]] & /@ {x1, x2, x3}`

Comment: Yes, but I want to assign the new list of variables into x1, x2, x3. Your code extracts the first two elements but won't store them in x1, x2, x3.

Comment: How about you create a function say `f[x_List]:=x[[{1,2}]];` then use `x1 = f[x1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica is a term rewriting system. It will replace `x1`, `x2`, `x3`  by their values as soon as possible. One solution is:

```
{x1,x2,x3} = #[[{1,2}]]&/@{x1,x2,x3}
```

We can make it shorter as:

```
{x1, x2, x3} //= #[[{1, 2}]] & /@ # &
```

Here `//=` is the "apply to" assignment operator. Basically `x //= f` is shorthand for `x=f[x]`.
Because `{x1,x2,x3}` appear on the left side of the assignment they won't be replaced by their values (due to the `HoldFirst` attribute of assignment), and the proper assignment will take place.

Comment: I didn't know this //=. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You can also obtain the assignments with precise evaluation control (eg.  using the `Hold`, `Release` `:>` operators)  for example as `Hold[z = z[[{1, 2}]]]  /. {z :> x1}` , but that seems rather tedious and to go against "the grain" of the language, so to speak.